# Dynamically select element based on value within href file path with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am messing around with Cheerio trying to build a for-fun web scraper with Cheerio, and hit a wall when it came to selecting elements using the href attribute in a table of elements. The reason I am trying to use the href attribute is that all the data elements have the exact same attributes except for different URLs. And each URL is also unique so I need to be able to select the element based on a shared file path such `/drivers/` or `/country/`. Below I have added a snippet from the HTML table I am trying to scrap as well as my Cheerio scraper so far.

index.ts

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

const entryPoint =
    'https://fiaresultsandstatistics.motorsportstats.com/results/1950-british-grand-prix';
const AxiosInstance = axios.create();

interface Entry {
    entry_number: string;
    driver: string;
    // country: string;
    // team: string;
    // car: string;
    // engine: string;
}

AxiosInstance.get(entryPoint)
    .then((response) => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const entryTable = $('._2xhp6 > tr');
        const entryList: Entry[] = [];

        entryTable.each((i, element) => {
            const entry_number = $(element).find('._1QeM8 > div').html();
            const driver = $(element)
                .find('td > a[contains(@href, "/drivers/")]')
                .html();
            // const country = $(element).find('f4AjL > a').html();
            entryList.push({
                entry_number,
                driver,
            });
        });

        console.log(entryList);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

HTML Table I am attempting to scrape

```html
<table class="_2Q90P">
    <thead class="ShIDs">
        <tr>
            <th class="_2sWDi _2efsK _1QeM8">
                <button type="button">#</button>
            </th>
            <th class="_2sWDi _2efsK f4AjL">
                <button type="button">Driver</button>
            </th>
            <th class="_2sWDi _2efsK f4AjL">
                <button type="button">Nat</button>
            </th>
            <th class="_2sWDi _2efsK f4AjL">
                <button type="button">Team</button>
            </th>
            <th class="_2sWDi _2efsK f4AjL">
                <button type="button">Car</button>
            </th>
            <th class="_2sWDi _2efsK f4AjL">
                <button type="button">Engine</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="_2xhp6">
        <tr class="_3AoAU">
            <td class="_2sWDi _1QeM8">
                <div
                    role="button"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    class="_1TRrV _6Jxl2"
                    ga-on="click,auxclick"
                    ga-event-category="Button Modal Window 1"
                    ga-event-action="click on Button Modal Window 1"
                >
                    1
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="_2sWDi f4AjL">
                <a
                    href="/drivers/juan-manuel-fangio/career"
                    role="button"
                    action="null"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    class="_1TRrV"
                    ga-on="click,auxclick,contextmenu"
                    ga-event-category=""
                    ga-event-action=""
                    >Juan Manuel Fangio</a
                >
            </td>
            <td class="_2sWDi f4AjL">
                <a
                    href="/countries/ARG"
                    role="button"
                    action="null"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    class="_1TRrV"
                    ga-on="click,auxclick,contextmenu"
                    ga-event-category=""
                    ga-event-action=""
                    >Argentina</a
                >
            </td>
            <td class="_2sWDi f4AjL">
                <a
                    href="/teams/alfa-romeo/history"
                    role="button"
                    action="null"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    class="_1TRrV"
                    ga-on="click,auxclick,contextmenu"
                    ga-event-category=""
                    ga-event-action=""
                    >Alfa Romeo SpA</a
                >
            </td>
            <td class="_2sWDi f4AjL">
                <div
                    role="button"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    class="_1TRrV _6Jxl2"
                    ga-on="click,auxclick"
                    ga-event-category="Button Modal Window Alfa Romeo 158"
                    ga-event-action="click on Button Modal Window Alfa Romeo 158"
                >
                    Alfa Romeo 158
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="_2sWDi f4AjL">
                <div
                    role="button"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    class="_1TRrV _6Jxl2"
                    ga-on="click,auxclick"
                    ga-event-category="Button Modal Window Alfa Romeo 158"
                    ga-event-action="click on Button Modal Window Alfa Romeo 158"
                >
                    Alfa Romeo 158
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  <tbody>
    ... next table row (also not sure why the developer of this page decided to make every row also its own individual tbody)
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also tried to use the Node.contains API and that does not seem to work either so I a bit lost with what to try next or if this is even possible?

Comment: So your problem is that this line `$(element).find('td > a[contains(@href, "/drivers/")]').html();` doesn't return anything?

Comment: Have you tried using [CSS attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) like `'td > a[href*="/drivers"]'` or `'td > a[href^="/drivers"]'` ?

Comment: I have not, as I have never seen attribute selectors before! That also worked! Thanks for your help Mauro!